# Am I going to run into problems with USB Fan Cooling for my PS3?

Tags: ps3

My PS3 is one of the original models with the ~60g Harddrive and PS2 Emulation. Since I live in Australia, it gets to 45+ degrees Celsius  (113 Fahrenheit), and when it gets excessively hot, so does my PS3.

Lately, I've been feeling around under the right side where the disk is inserted and the fan blows out from, and it's been getting fairly hot.

I recently brought a bunch of USB Fans, and with a USB Hub, plugged them all up. Two point to the problem zone, while two attempt to circulate the air in the cupboard, as some of the heat remains inside. The two that I have set up aiming at the PS3 are roughly like this

```
________________
                |  --->
--------        |  --->
      [         |] --->  Hot Air
      [         |] --->
  ____[_________|] --->     
  |        __              \  /
  |       |\              \  /
  |         \            \  /       <---USB Fans (They'd be lined up)
  |___       \          \  / \---|
      \       Hot Area \  /   \  |
______|                  /     \ |
_________________________________|
```

In case if my image doesn't correctly show it, this is the kind of fan I bought

[image: fan]

> Brand new in box  - dimension 143L 85W 141H mm 
>   USB powered - ideal for desktop,laptop cooling or personal use 
>   USB cable - about 1.2 meter 
>   purely metal made structure for stability including 
>   Aluminum made blade. 
>   rotary fan head 
>   rubber base support to reduce noise 
>   switch on/off on the back 
>   quite operation but very powerful 2.5w 
>   3 month replacement warranty  
>   7days full refund guaranteed if you are unhappy with quality !

[Source - eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/250976562268)

Now I am wondering, since the vent is blowing out hot air and the area the fans are aimed at also include the possibility that air will be blown back into the vent, I am wondering what, if any, potential problems I could run into (ie. blowing dust in, stopping hot air being blow out)

NOTE: I did try them out and the hot area kept cool; however, I don't know what's going on inside and am unsure if the PS3's internal fan is stronger (it sure is louder though)

Comment: No. Dont do this. Really. The console has a ventilation system that takes cool air in and blows warm air out. Put the fans on the other side where the air goes in(i strongly dont encourage this). If your console is hot. its fine. If your console is too hot and is affecting gameplay or starts crashing, dont resort to fans. Resort to taking the thing to a store and getting the thing cleaned. Dust gets stuck in there all the time. Proper maintanence and you dont need these fans.

Comment: Oh yes. Reason why i discourage this is because if you put these fans to blow air in the vents the right way, what you initally cause is for the fans to spin faster. And that causes a voltage to go out which can potentially damage or even fry the fan causing even more trouble. Get the console cleaned. If its still hot after that. Then ask a professional what sort of things that you can do. DONT STUFF MORE AIR INTO THE MACHINE.

Comment: @Jonathan so the 2 fans i have to circulate the air inside the cupboard is fine then?

Comment: Dont circulate air. the hot air must blow away from the console. The last thing that you want is to cycle the same air around the console. IT gets too hot. You need new cold air to go in and warm air to go somewhere else. http://www.yellowlightofdeath.com/ps3-cooling-fans-reviewed/ you may be able to find something also helpful there. But best would be to go and see a professional and get expert advice.